# NUnit: How to start a test only with one userRole, while there are 3 different userRoles defined in TestFixture

Tags: nunit, test-fixture

I have a "Regression Test" Class in which i defined 3 different user Roles in the TestFixture
[image]

In the regression test i'm testing other web app functionalities beside of the main feature functionalities. Currently im having there 5 different tests as seen below in the screenshot.
[image]

What i want now is, that the first 4 Test Methods will be started ONLY with the `admin` user Role, and the last Test Method called `UserRights` should be tested only with `hsuINT` and `hsuIntRequest`

The problem im having right now is, that all the 5 Test Methods will be started with all userRoles defined at the class in TestFixture

[image]

Is there a way, how to tell the TestMethod with which UserRole it should start the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NUnit, the primary purpose of a TestFixture is to group together all the tests that need a common setup. So if the first four tests require the user role `admin`, and the last one requires running under two different roles, they don't belong in the same TestFixture.

You can restructure your tests into two fixtures, similar to this:

```
[TestFixture("adminInt")]
public class FirstFixture
{
    // Your first four tests here
}

[TestFixture("hsuINT")]
[TestFixture("hsuIntRequest")]
public class SecondFixture
{
    // Your last test here
}
```

Of course, the first fixture doesn't really need a parameter... you can hard code the role if you prefer.

If splitting the fixture requires duplicating a lot of setup code (which you don't show in the question) you can derive each class from a common base, which has the setup. In that case, all three classes should have the parameter but only the two derived classes should have the TestFixture attribute.

Comment: Too bad but thanks for the info! I created a new class just for this one testcase, which is fine!